# Cannot set monitor to use 2560x1440

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 14.10, resolution, nvidia-optimus

I have a laptop and am trying to plug in two monitors, one of which should run at `2560x1440`

I have installed the proprietary `nvidia-331-updates` drivers and (I think) configured it to use those by default (`prime-select nvidia`)

I have an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz` and an `Nvidia 710m` runnung Ubuntu 14.10

When I try to set the resolution via:

```
~$ cvt 2560 1440
~$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "2560x1440_60.00"
~$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00
```

I get the error: `xrandr: Configure crtc 2 failed`

The output of `xrandr --verbose`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4366 x 2560, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+3000+1512 (0x49) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  1477952
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0006afec3100000000
        0015010495221378020bb59757548c26
        23505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101121b5646500023302616
        360058c1100000180000000f00000000
        00000000000000000020000000fe0041
        554f0a202020202020202020000000fe
        004231353658544e30332e31200a002e
    BACKLIGHT: 976 
        range: (0, 976)
    Backlight: 976 
        range: (0, 976)
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1366x768 (0x49)   69.3MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1366 start 1404 end 1426 total 1436 skew    0 clock   48.3KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  803           clock   60.1Hz
  1360x768 (0xb4)   84.8MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock   47.7KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock   59.8Hz
  1360x768 (0xb5)   72.0MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock   47.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock   60.0Hz
  1024x768 (0xb6)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0xb7)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0xb8)   36.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
  640x480 (0xb9)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+596 (0xba) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  1477952
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     HDMI1
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0009d1d67845540000
        2b1801030e3c22782e0cd5a9554ca125
        0d5054a56b80818081c08100a9c0b300
        d1c001010101023a801871382d40582c
        450055502100001e000000ff00524145
        30303833393031390a20000000fd0032
        4c1e5911000a202020202020000000fc
        0042656e51204757323736350a200025
  1920x1080 (0xba)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1680x1050 (0xbb)  146.2MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock   60.0Hz
  1600x900 (0xbc)  119.0MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1864 total 2128 skew    0 clock   55.9KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0xbd)  135.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   80.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   75.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0xbe)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x800 (0xbf)   83.5MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock   49.7KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock   59.8Hz
  1152x864 (0xc0)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock   75.0Hz
  1280x720 (0xc1)   74.4MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1336 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock   44.7KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock   60.0Hz
  1024x768 (0xc2)   78.8MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock   60.1KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock   75.1Hz
  1024x768 (0xb6)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  832x624 (0xc3)   57.3MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock   49.7KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock   74.6Hz
  800x600 (0xc4)   49.5MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock   46.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock   75.0Hz
  800x600 (0xb7)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  640x480 (0xc5)   31.5MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock   37.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock   75.0Hz
  640x480 (0xc6)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  720x400 (0xc7)   28.3MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock   70.1Hz
HDMI1 connected 1080x1920+1920+0 (0xba) left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
    Identifier: 0x45
    Timestamp:  1477952
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     VGA1
    CRTC:       2
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0009d1d67845540000
        2b180103803c2278260cd5a9554ca125
        0d5054a56b80818081c08100a9c0b300
        d1c001010101565e00a0a0a029503020
        350055502100001a000000ff00524145
        30303834323031390a20000000fd0032
        4c1e591b000a202020202020000000fc
        0042656e51204757323736350a2001db
        020322f14f901f051404130312071615
        01061102230907078301000065030c00
        1000023a801871382d40582c45005650
        2100001f011d8018711c1620582c2500
        56502100009f011d007251d01e206e28
        550056502100001e8c0ad08a20e02d10
        103e9600565021000018000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000047
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
  1920x1080 (0xba)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync *current
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0xc8)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock   56.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   50.0Hz
  1920x1080 (0xc9)  148.4MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.4KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   59.9Hz
  1920x1080i (0xca)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.8KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   60.1Hz
  1920x1080i (0xcb)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock   28.1KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   50.0Hz
  1920x1080i (0xcc)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   33.7KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1680x1050 (0xcd)  119.0MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock   64.7KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock   59.9Hz
  1600x900 (0xbc)  119.0MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1864 total 2128 skew    0 clock   55.9KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0xbd)  135.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   80.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   75.0Hz
  1280x1024 (0xbe)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock   64.0KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x800 (0xce)   71.0MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock   49.3KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock   59.9Hz
  1152x864 (0xc0)  108.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock   75.0Hz
  1280x720 (0xcf)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock   45.0KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x720 (0xd0)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock   37.5KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   50.0Hz
  1280x720 (0xd1)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock   45.0KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   59.9Hz
  1440x576i (0xd2)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1590 total 1728 skew    0 clock   15.6KHz
        v: height  576 start  580 end  586 total  625           clock   50.1Hz
  1024x768 (0xc2)   78.8MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock   60.1KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock   75.1Hz
  1024x768 (0xb6)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  1440x480i (0xd3)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width  1440 start 1478 end 1602 total 1716 skew    0 clock   15.8KHz
        v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock   60.1Hz
  1440x480i (0xd4)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync Interlace
        h: width  1440 start 1478 end 1602 total 1716 skew    0 clock   15.7KHz
        v: height  480 start  488 end  494 total  525           clock   60.1Hz
  832x624 (0xc3)   57.3MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock   49.7KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock   74.6Hz
  800x600 (0xc4)   49.5MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock   46.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock   75.0Hz
  800x600 (0xb7)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  720x576 (0xd5)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock   31.2KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock   50.0Hz
  720x480 (0xd6)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  720x480 (0xd7)   27.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
  640x480 (0xc5)   31.5MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock   37.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock   75.0Hz
  640x480 (0xc6)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
  640x480 (0xb9)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
  720x400 (0xc7)   28.3MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock   70.1Hz
  2560x1440_60.00 (0xf6)  312.2MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock   89.5KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock   60.0Hz
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x46
    Timestamp:  1477952
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x47
    Timestamp:  1477952
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: :
```

UPDATE:

Following instructions here:
https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/HQsCY7ErAL4
I was able to get it to output without the erro, however now my monitor has an "out of range" error

Comment: It looks like you have your output cloned on both HDMI and VGA, and VGA can't go higher than 1920 x 1080.

Comment: Correct, I have two of the same monitor, I want to set one (hdmi) to 2560, the other can stay at 1080

Comment: Then you need to configure them as two separate monitors rather than one mirroring the exact contents of the other.

Comment: @psusi they are two separate monitors, they extend not mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the nvidia-settings -> X Server Display Configuration -> Detect displays. I've successfully used it to display the desktop on two monitors (one @2550x1440, the other @1920x1080).

Comment: In Nvidia-settings I see two categories, application profiles and Nvidia-settings configuration, neither have detect displays

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry but you are out of luck. Displaying `2560x1440` pixels requires using a higher graphics chip frequency and even if this is within the spec of the chip the laptop manufacturers disable anything above `1920x1080` to prevent overheating.

I am yet to see a laptop whose spec says `Support of external monitor @2560x1440 pixels` .

You can use your shiny monitor with a desktop workstation having discrete card with an HDMI output - provided that that resolution is within the spec of the card.

Comment: do you have a source for this? sounds a bit hard to believe as i thought it depends on the version of HDMI, not the graphics card, and according to [this](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-710m/specifications) the 710m supports it

Comment: Yes, the chipset may be able to support it but the laptop manufacturer has probably limited the resolution to HD. I suggest you double-check your laptop specifications and/or contact the supplier/manufacturer.

Comment: Check out this link: http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/solved-outputting-2560x1440-1440p-signal-via-hdmi-output.734218/ . Quote: "I had to go into nVidia Control Panel and set a custom resolution of 2560x1440 @ 55Hz (could not get 60Hz to be stable). But at the very minimum, I am now running a Lenovo Ideapad Y500p that outputs native resolution to a 1440p display through its HDMI port.

Comment: On the spec for nvidia quadro k2100m (which is in the HP ZBook) its stated: `Furthermore, high resolution monitors of up to 3840 x 2160 pixels can now be connected using DisplayPort 1.2 or HDMI 1.4a if available.`. Ref: http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-Quadro-K2100M.98900.0.html

Comment: Would the Nvidia Control Panel be the "NVIDIA X Server Settings"? I'm looking at it but none of it looks like i can set resolution anywhere.
@stalet I have a 710m in an acer aspire v4

Comment: @stalet you link to a chipset feature which may or (most likely) may not be enabled in the actual laptop being shipped to end users.

Comment: @Epicblood 2560x1440 uses almost twice as many pixels as 1920x1080. This means twice as high pixel frequency if using the same frame rate. If you are able to reduce the frame rate you may be able to stay within the frequency limit imposed by components between the chipset and the HDMI port. Try replacing the `_60.00` part in your `xrandr` commands with `_40.00` or `_30.00` and see if that will help.

Comment: @sмurf same error when I do `_30.00`

Comment: @sмurf I got it to output, but now monitor gives out of range error

Comment: If the GPU supports it, then it supports it; the system builder can't disable it.  Also it doesn't produce any more heat to run the monitor in a higher resolution.

Comment: @Epicblood i cant find the documentation for your aspire v4 - so its hard to tell whether it might support it or not.

Comment: @sмurf for the zbook it also states in the documentation that is supports higher resolution: http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA5-4926ENW

Comment: @stalet thanks for that link. So they started supporting higher resolution on external monitors, that is exciting. Still note the outputs are DP not HDMI. I am curious whether there are laptops supporting HDMI output at higher res.